# how do I get rid of the following error in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

The error I get is exactly the error specified in:

http://java.syntaxerrors.info/index.php?title=Own_file

(class must be defined in its own file.)

but they don't give a solution there how to solve it, other than just having a file per public class.

Thank you, eclipse, for making me do this, but this is not mandatory in Java. Is there a way to get rid of this error?

Comment: Are you sure about " but this is not mandatory in Java"? Even javac complains, if the name of the class isn't the same as the file name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is mandatory in Java. Each public class has to be in a separate file named exactly the same way as the class.

[See this question about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134784/why-filename-in-java-should-be-same-as-class-name). The Java language specification writes that this is not 100% mandatory for compilers, but they usually do that. And since it is a good thing, and is noted in the spec, all compilers do it.

> When packages are stored in a file system (§7.2.1), the host system may choose to enforce the restriction that it is a compile-time error if a type is not found in a file under a name composed of the type name plus an extension (such as .java or .jav)

If you want to have multiple classes in the same file, that's a different story. You can do it in two ways:

- declare them as package-private classes with `class Foo` after the body of the main class. You can have any number of non-public classes in the same file
- declare them as static inner classes: `public static class InnerFoo` inside the main class body. That way they will be visible to other classes by `FooClass.InnerFoo`

Comment: this is a silly restriction. I have many classes which inherit from the same class, all very short classes which have a very specific role. I see no reason why not to condense them all in the same source file. I am also pretty sure I used to do that in other cases, but I haven't been using java for a while. maybe it is now enforced in newer versions of Java.

Comment: it is not a silly restriction at all. You have multiple options for 'condensing' them, see my update

Comment: @kloop If you have many subclasses that are very small, you can declare them as `public static class SubClass extends YourClass {}` *inside* the class declaration of `YourClass`.

Comment: I think "private" is not the correct designation for a class without access modifier, shouldn't it be "default access" (or "package private")? Private classes are only allowed as member classes, not as top level classes.