# how to use a class in the java file containing multiple classes

Tags: java, class, syntax

For example,

```
//Package1/File1.java
class A{
...
}

public class File1{
...
}
```

How can I use the class A in the different File2.java? And what's the package that A is belong to? Package1 or default? Thank you!

Comment: Try to google it, there are more than alot explanations across the internet.

Comment: Go and start learning java from a good text-book!

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. Create an instance of the class `File1` inside the main method of `File2.java` and do all your work there.

```
//package1/File2.java

public class File2
{
    ...
}

public File2()  //constructor
{

}

//Main method
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    File1 f1 = new File1();
    //do your rest of the work here
}
```

You can't use the class A in `File2.java` because it's not public, and you can't have more than one public class in a .java file.

In order to access class A inside `File2.java`, you have to create another java class named A in another java file named `A.java`, and then make this A class public, and create instance of A inside `File2.java`.

Inside `A.java`:

```
 //package1/A.java
 public class A{
    ...
 }

 public A() //constructor
 {
     ...
 }
```

Now in `File2.java` :

```
 //package1/File2.java 
 public class File2()
 {
     ...
 }

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
     A objA = new A();
     //do your rest of the work here
 }
```

Go through the following link for a better understanding: [Why can't two public classes be defined in one file in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13329012/why-cant-two-public-classes-be-defined-in-one-file-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Both the file belong to same package that package1/file1.java.
See understand like this : A class like file1.java can have many sub classes as "class A" but the public class can only be that class which has same name as file (file1.java) class.
I think I make some sense here.