# Main.java uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details

Tags: java

Main.java:3: class Holeintext is public, should be declared in a file named Holeintext.java public class Holeintext 
{ ^ 
Note: Main.java uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details. 1 error

this is error i m getting this is an compilation error can someone tell me how to solve this. please help.
while compiling on my pc it is running with out any error but the moment i upload it on site to compile it show me this error.

the code is :

```
package holeintext;
import java.io.*;
class Holeintext {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO code application logic here
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(System.in);
        String s;
        char[] str;
        System.out.println("INPUT:");
        int c = Integer.parseInt( in .readLine());
        String[] str1 = new String[c];
        for (int m = 0; m < c; m++) {
            s = in .readLine();
            str1[m] = s; //at this point we have a array with our input
        }
        System.out.println("OUTPUT:");
        for (int g = 0; g < str1.length; g++) {
            s = str1[g];
            str = s.toCharArray();
            int i = 0;
            int count = 0;
            while (i < str.length) {
                if ((str[i] == 'A') || (str[i] == 'D') || (str[i] == 'O') ||
                    (str[i] == 'P') || (str[i] == 'R')) {
                    count = count + 1;
                } else
                if (str[i] == 'B') {
                    count = count + 2;
                }
                i++;
            }
            System.out.println(count);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: post your code and also format properly the existing question

Comment: Can you post the code please?

Comment: This question does not have enough info to answer. Maybe the Java versions differ in different systems?

Comment: @dARKpRINCE On the contrary, the error message in the question has so much information in it that the question didn't even need to be asked.

Comment: @EJP: Your right, I was looking too deep into the error. :)

Answer (score 2):

In java public classes must be in files with corresponding name. So class `Dog` must be in file `Dog.java`. Deprecation is not a compiler error, but classname-filename is.

Answer (score 2):

From error I can guess, you have saved file with another name other than class name `Holeintext`

```
public class Holeintext {
 ...
 ....
}
```

**Solution:**

1.Remove public access- specifier from class

```
class Holeintext{  
 ....  
 ...   
}
```

2.or save file with `Holeintext.java`

**Useful links**

- [why-filename-in-java-should-be-same-as-class-name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2134784/1031945)
- [why-must-a-java-file-have-the-same-name-as-its-public-class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10443341/1031945)

Comment: i have remove public access- specifier from class and now it is working but i got runtime error now

Comment: what is the `runtime error`? Please edit question and post the code & tell error.

Comment: i have just posted the code have a look

Comment: @user2885489: what is the error name? I checked your code, but seems there is no error. Please tell me name of error. I think because of package you are facing problem in running program from command prompt.

Comment: Even me too not get what is the error but the moment i upload it on site it just show me a runtime error no other description is given

Comment: i got it when i remove that package it is working thank u

Comment: @user2885489: If my answer solved your problem then please mark as an answer see [link1](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/203266) [link2](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/203266)