# Same name for class and file,Why?

Tags: java

Why do we have to save a file with the name same as that of class name of a public class?

```
public class Indian{ 
     public static void main (String args []){
          System.out.println ("i am a programmer");
     }
}
```

This class must be saved with the name Indian.Why so, is it a convention??

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442758/why-must-a-java-file-have-the-same-name-as-its-public-class

Comment: If it were so that was for users convinience then the compiler must not give error...but it does so this means that it is not a practice but made mandatory by the compiler....is there any technical logic to it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this applies only to public classes; package-private classes can go into files of any name. For public classes this is a convention, along the same lines as the placement of files in directories that mirror the structure of your packages, and using `.java` extension.

This is done so that Java compiler can find classes without examining all Java files in the folder.

Note that the convention does not need to be universal: Java supplies a standard that is available to anyone to implement, so one could build a system where Java source files are placed in a database or in a cloud instead of a regular file system. Developers of this Java implementation could theoretically come up with a different convention altogether, or not use any conventions at all.

Answer (score 5):

Because it's a constraint imposed by the Java compiler. Why is it so? For order, simply. Imagine a huge project with 300 classes, and all of them containing classes with different names.

Comment: Just wanted to comment that 300 isn't all that huge for number of classes. Think of projects with thousands of classes for large projects.

Comment: Sure, but 300 is already more than enough to get you completely confused, if that simple rule didn't apply ;)