# why if my file name and public class name differs then i get compile error?

Tags: java, constructor, compiler-errors, access-specifier

```
public class constprac {

    public static void main(String args[]  )
    {
        consttest class1=new consttest("ria");
        class1.showName();
    }
}
```

```
**public** class consttest{
    String gname;
    public consttest(String name){``
        gname=name;
    }
    public String setName(){
        return gname;
    }
    public void showName(){
        System.out.println("YOUR 1ST GirlFriend IS "+ setName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named "What topics can I ask about here?" and "What types of questions should I avoid asking?". And more importantly, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This is how Java designed it. See


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841847/can-i-compile-a-java-file-with-a-different-name-than-the-class

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442758/why-must-a-java-file-have-the-same-name-as-its-public-class

Comment: This is how Java designed it. See below links

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442758/why-must-a-java-file-have-the-same-name-as-its-public-class

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841847/can-i-compile-a-java-file-with-a-different-name-than-the-class

Answer (score 2):

> why if my file name and public class name differs then i get compile error?

Because that's how Java is defined: If you have a **public** class, it must be in a file named after the public class.

The details can be found in [§7 of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html). It's essentially saying that if source code is stored in a file system, a certain set of requirements are imposed in order to make the package system work in a consistent way.

Comment: User know that rule. He is asking for the reason behind it. `that's how Java is defined` is not an answer.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ: I don't see any evidence of that.

Comment: what you said is correct in case of main class. But why compile error occurs if i change the class name in other sub class with access specifier named pubilc?

Comment: @AkashPrabhakar: I'm sorry, I don't know what you mean by "its correct in main class".

Comment: @T.J.Crowder if i ignore public or delete public in                           **public** class consttest{
    String gname;
    public consttest(String name){``
        gname=name;
    }
    public String setName(){
        return gname;
    }
    public void showName(){
        System.out.println("YOUR 1ST GirlFriend IS "+ setName());
    }
}                                        my program works completely fine why so?

Comment: @AkashPrabhakar Stop beating over the bush. You are making nosense. The link (http://csis.pace.edu/~bergin/KarelJava2ed/ch2/javamain.html) might help you to understand. Go read and ask further doubts if you have any.

Comment: @AkashPrabhakar: You've started a sentence ("if i ignore public or delete public") and never finished it. If you do that, **what**? You mean it compiles? Right, because as I said above, the restriction relates to **public** classes.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ 'Because that's the way Java is defined' is the only answer anybody's going to get, unless you can get Jim Gosling or God in on the call.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ thank you so much for your response i am the beginner for java programming as we as stack over flow

Comment: @T.J.Crowder THANK YOU so much for your response as i said i am the beginner for java programming .