# In USACO, this compiler keeps appearing

Tags: java

```
ride.java:8: class Ride is public, should be declared in a file named Ride.java
public class Ride {
       ^
1 error
```

This is my code

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.io.*;

public class Ride {

    static Scanner reader;
    static PrintWriter outFile;
    int num = 0;
    int total_c = 0;
    int total_g = 0;
    char [] comet = new char [6];
    char [] group = new char [6];

    public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception
    {
        reader = new Scanner(new File("ride.in"));
        outFile = new PrintWriter(new File("ride.out"));
        Ride r = new Ride();
        r.run();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        char in = '\0';
        int x = 0;
        while(reader.hasNext())
        {
            in = reader.next().charAt(0);
            if(x<6)
            {
                comet[x] = in;
            }
            else 
            {
                group[x-6] = in;
            }
            x++;
        } 

        for(int a = 0; a < 6; a++)
        {
            total_c *= (int)(comet[a]-64);
            total_g *= (int)(group[a]-64);
        }

        if(total_c%47 == total_g%47)
        {
            outFile.print("GO");
        }
        else
            outFile.print("STAY");
    }
}
```

I do have the file under Ride.java, however USACO cannot compile the program.

Comment: `ride.java:8: class Ride is public, should be declared in a file named Ride.java` Did you mix up `ride.java` with `Ride.java`?

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you declare a single class with different file name. For a simple reminder:

> Java file name must be same as public class name.

[@deco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1029272/deco) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10443341/4758255) can give you more details about it.