# Why public class are named same as sourve file in java

Tags: java, class, filenames

Why public class are named same as source file in java.and
Why non public class are not required to to have same file and class name

Comment: It's a design decision, mainly because a non-`public` class can't be accessed from outside the package so there's no need to make it trivial to find.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134784/why-are-filenames-in-java-the-same-as-the-public-class-name

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442758/why-must-a-java-file-have-the-same-name-as-its-public-class

Comment: @RaghvendraKumar:  Got any more?

Comment: @Makoto no I think that's it.