# Design Pattern within a java class

Tags: java, design-patterns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: Multiple class declarations in one file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336692/java-multiple-class-declarations-in-one-file)

Recently I was going through a java class in which I have discovered that it was a java class with the named A but after that  there was another class named B was written after Class A in the same java file  ..like this

```
class A
{


} 

Class B
{

}
```

but the class was finally saved with the name A.java , Please let me know is it any kind of design pattern ..!!

Comment: It is not really a design pattern. Just something author decided to do. This is not usually done in practice.

Comment: Looks like it has already been discussed here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336692/java-multiple-class-declarations-in-one-file][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336692/java-multiple-class-declarations-in-one-file

Answer (score 7):

Not a design pattern.

You can have more than 1 java class written in a single file but the name of the file should be the same name as the **public** class in the file.

[Why are filenames in Java the same as the class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134784/why-filename-in-java-should-be-same-as-class-name)

Answer (score 2):

At most one public class is allowed in a java file and file name must match with the name of public class (if there is any).

I am not aware of any design pattern that uses this technique (or rather flexibility).

Answer (score 0):

There is no design pattern here. Due to the fact that there was no public class declaration, the one file could be called either `A.java` or `B.java`.