# Could not find or load main class in Win7 or Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in OSX

Tags: java, windows, macos

I see there're plenty of analogical threads here but they didn't help me.

I've tried to run in Win7 and OSX Mountain Lion:
1) java Test
2) java -cp . Test

```
//Test.java
class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

1) for Win7 error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class Test

2) OSX Mountain Lion error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Test Caused
>   by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Test
>              at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)

Really have no idea what's wrong here... :(

Thanks,
Oscar

Comment: Where does(folder) it create class file?

Comment: The way I try to run it should create .class file in the same directory with .java file

Comment: Though it's stupid to ask but still want to confirm... Did you create class file using javac?

Comment: As I already mentioned javac works fine for me. Now I relalised that I was wrong thinking that java could also compile. I posted really stupid question.

Comment: Do u mean to say that you did not run javac? In that case, problem is solved...

Comment: Yes, in this case I was trying to compile using java (without javac). Now I'm sure I was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the file should be the same as the class name `which is public` and has the main() method.
In your case rename the file name from `Test.java` will compile and will create HelloWorld.class file not Test.class because there is no Test class declared in your file.

after .class file is created , run it with `java HelloWorld`

[To Know More click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146576/why-is-the-java-main-method-static)  and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134784/why-filename-in-java-should-be-same-as-class-name)

so here's an example

```
//Filename abc.java
public class hi
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
 System.out.println("Hell");
}
}
```

the output

```
abc.java:1: class hi is public, should be declared in a file named hi.java
public class hi
       ^
1 error
```

but if you do this

```
 //Filename abc.java
    class hi
    {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
     System.out.println("Hell");
    }
    }
```

it will create hi.class file so

```
D:\>java hi
Hell
```

Comment: Renaming file name to HelloWorld.java still giving same error.

Comment: Are you sure you renamed it to HelloWorld.java ?

Comment: did you compile it first 1)javac HelloWorld.java  2)java HelloWorld. Also, check whether you have jdk and jre

Comment: No. As I understand I can use java to compile if there's a main method. And I have it: public static void main(String[] args)

Comment: javac works fine. The problem is compiling with java. I want to generate HelloWorld.class using "java HelloWorld"

Comment: No you have to compile it first to create a .class file first run `javac HelloWorld.java` then `java HelloWorld`

Comment: I've read that I can compile and run, if there's a main method with the steps: 1) java HelloWorld . Then it generates HelloWorld.class, which I can run then with 2) java HelloWorld.class. Am I wrong?

Comment: Bhavik, the name of the .java file has nothing to do with the name of the .class file, which will always be correct.

Comment: The name of the file should be the same as the class name which is public and has the main() method... this is incorrect... See first answer in this post.

Comment: Sorry buddy, I think lot of people has answered in the similar fashion. So downvoting your post does not make sense, but due to site's policy I can not remove my downvote until unless u edit ur answer..

Answer (score 1):

My `Test.java`:

```
class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("HW");
  }
}
```

My dialog with `bash`:

```bsh
Neoten:bin marko$ ls -al
total 8
drwxr-xr-x   .
drwxr-xr-x   ..
-rw-r--r--   HelloWorld.class
drwxr-xr-x   test
Neoten:bin marko$ java HelloWorld
HW
Neoten:bin marko$
```

You didn't post the contents of the directory where you ran it, so this is the most probable cause of your errors.

Comment: All I want to do is to compile with java (not javac)

Comment: Then you should learn the very basics of Java: `java` starts up the JVM, which loads the compiled `.class` files. It has no business with `.java` files.

Comment: Do mean I can't compile HelloWorld.java by running 'java HelloWorld' ?

Comment: Yes, I most definitely mean that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your class must have same name as file name.
`test.java` must contain `class test`

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help. I remember Eclipse used to complain that name of a class should be the same as a declared class and with capital letter. javac Test.java works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You must have your class name the same as your file, and your classes directory location translatable to your classes package. This is how Java supports namespaces, and having no package declared is called the default namespace - it's not recommended to use the default namespace.

i.e.

```
// my/name/space/HelloWorld.java
package my.name.space;

public class HelloWorld {
    ...
}
```