# main method with class name and file name

Tags: java, eclipse, program-entry-point

My file name is Temp.java and inside it I have this. I'm using eclipse IDE

```
/*package*/ class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("test");
    }
}
```

So I was unable to run this as java application. I change my class name to Temp

```
class Temp {
 ....
}
```

Now I can. Can someone explain me why ?

Comment: @assylias this is related to main method and class name

Comment: @null Sorry I missed that. For what it's worth, both compile in Netbeans.

Comment: I think this should not be close this is related to eclipse,file name , class name name and main method. Check the answer of "assylias" it worked on netbeans.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably a limitation of Eclipse. The code runs well from command line.

As I understand, you are trying to embed your unit tests in the same file with the class under test. This is a nice idea and I totally concur with it. You can read more about how you can succeed in [Ben J. Christensen's blog post](http://benjchristensen.com/2011/10/23/junit-tests-as-inner-classes/). Generally, he suggests placing the tests in a static inner class, not a standalone class in the same file.

An example from the Netflix Hystrix framework: [HystrixCircuitBreaker.UnitTest](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/blob/master/hystrix-core/src/main/java/com/netflix/hystrix/HystrixCircuitBreaker.java#L281)

Answer (score 1):

The class (which `main` should be run) inside the `.java` file must have the same name as the file. If the class is not public (as in your case) the class will compile but it can't be run since Eclipse tries to load the class according to the file name.

Comment: This is true if the class is public, you can put numerous non-public classes into a .java file.

Comment: @null OK, it is not public so it compiles. But you have asked why it is not running.

Answer (score 1):

The code below, located in `Temp.java`, compiles and runs fine with Netbeans:

```
class Whatever {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with eclipse, i think you are trying to run using `right click -> run as -> Java Application`, unfortunately eclipse is not showing this option if the class is not public.
But you can still run the class using `Alt+Shift+X,J`.
Its not the problem with Java, its with Eclipse.

Comment: +1 for The problem is with eclipse ,,, it not showing if the class name and file name is different, not related to public.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the file should be the same as the class name which is public and has the main() method. In your first case the file name Temp.java will compile and will create Test.class file not Temp.class because there is no Temp class declared in your file.

after .class file is created , run it with `java Test`

so here's an example

```
//Filename abc.java
public class hi
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
 System.out.println("Hell");
}
}
```

the output

```
abc.java:1: class hi is public, should be declared in a file named hi.java
public class hi
       ^
1 error
```

but if you do this

```
 //Filename abc.java
    class hi
    {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
     System.out.println("Hell");
    }
    }
```

it will create hi.class file so

```
D:\>java hi
Hell
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13739925/could-not-find-or-load-main-class-in-win7-or-exception-in-thread-main-java-lan/13740004#comment18882499_13740004