# why to save the name of java program with the same main class name in case of public main class

Tags: java

why is it necessary to save the name of java program with the main class name when that class is public, if the class is not public then we can save the program with any name and then can compile it. why in case of public main class we can not do that.?

Comment: I'm afraid your question is fairly unclear. Perhaps some code examples of what you think you can and can't do would help. (Also: "Save" *where*?)

Comment: @LoganDam While your edit might be correct I think the OP is maybe confused about some things and could benefit from some clarifications. Those clarification would not happen with the way you rewrote the question.

Comment: @madth3: Indeed, it wasn't at all clear to me that the edit didn't change things.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question means, why does a public class name needs to match the name of the file it's been declared in.

I think this answer by Bill K would answer your question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2134888/1401409

Answer (score 0):

No it is not necessary .  You can save the file containing class say `MainClass` containing `main method` with any other name say `NonMainClass.java` (given that the file doesn't contain any other public class). You can compile the same using `javac NonMainClass.java` . But when executing it you need to execute it using `java MainClass`.

For Example. Consider the code given below:

```
class MainsClass 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

This file is saved as `NoMainClass.java`. And it is compiled as `javac NoMainClass.java`. It generates the `MainClass.class` in working directory. And to execute the program you need to run following command `java MainClass` .