# java file changing from Fibonacci.java to MyFirstApp.class

Tags: java, eclipse, class

I just installed java and am trying to compile sample code. I copied a Fibonacci sequence program into Notepad, saved it as "Fibonacci.java" and compiled it in Windows command prompt as such:

javac Fibonacci.java

The output: MyFirstApp.class

MyFirstApp is the name for another thing I'm working on in Eclipse. What's going on?

THanks for help.

Code:

```
public class Fibonacci {

   public static void main(String[] args) { 
      int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
      int f = 0, g = 1;

      for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
      f = f + g;
      g = f - g;
       System.out.println(f); 
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Is the name of the class in Fibonacci.java `Fibanacci`? Also, are you sure you are looking for the resulting class file in the right place?

Comment: have a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134784/why-filename-in-java-should-be-same-as-class-name)

Comment: Fibonacci is spelled correctly, and I am not sure I am looking for the file in the right place. I have no clue what is going on w/all the directories among Java, Eclipse and the OUYA-ODK I'm trying to learn.

Comment: Be sure Eclipse is compiling what you think it's compiling.

Comment: @Fluxcapacitor - At the command prom, before invoking Java compiler try `DIR *.java` and see whether the source code you're trying to compile is indeed in this directory.

Answer (score 0):

please send us the source code.

Could be as simple as you forgot to change in the sourcecode from

```
class MyFirstApp { ....
```

To

```
class Fibonacci { ...
```

???

And your class file is an old output file from earlier compilation?

Comment: This is not an answer, it should have been a comment.

Comment: Sotirios, did you see my write a PUBLIC class? No! The code I wrote is 100% free from errors. Compilation error would thrown if the class was addressed as public and the filename is not matched. I think my answer is the closest to the question, but I see now that the sourceode he just gave is a public class Fibon.... But he might have changed the code. Can thread owner please tell the status of this error.