# How do I compile a single java file into a class file? (I'm not a programmer)

Tags: java, class, compilation, minecraft

Okay so basically I have these two Minecraft mods that both modify the bfj.class file and so I decompiled the files using an online decompiler here: http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=preview I then copied the code from one file and put it at the end of the other file and saved it as a .java file. Now I do not know if this will work or if I need to reprogram the files (I don't know how to program) but what I would like to try is recompiling the one java file into one file. I do not have any other files except the two compiled files which I decompiled and merged and the merged .java file... How do I convert the java file into a class file with missing files??? For example when I try to compile I get these errors:

```
C:\Users\*******\Desktop\New folder>javac bfj.java
bfj.java:3917: error: class, interface, or enum expected
import cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.Side;
^
bfj.java:3918: error: class, interface, or enum expected
import cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.SideOnly;
^
bfj.java:3919: error: class, interface, or enum expected
import java.io.FileInputStream;
^
bfj.java:3920: error: class, interface, or enum expected
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
^
bfj.java:3921: error: class, interface, or enum expected
import java.io.IOException;
^
bfj.java:3922: error: class, interface, or enum expected
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
^
bfj.java:3923: error: class, interface, or enum expected
import java.net.URL;
^
bfj.java:3924: error: class, interface, or enum expected
import java.util.Properties;
^
bfj.java:3925: error: class, interface, or enum expected
import java.util.Random;
^
bfj.java:3926: error: class, interface, or enum expected
import net.minecraft.client.Minecraft;
^
bfj.java:3927: error: class, interface, or enum expected
import net.minecraftforge.common.MinecraftForge;
^
bfj.java:3928: error: class, interface, or enum expected
import net.minecraftforge.event.EventBus;
^
bfj.java:3929: error: class, interface, or enum expected
import net.minecraftforge.event.entity.PlaySoundAtEntityEvent;
```

Any ideas on what I need to do and/or if this will work if we can get it to compile?

Comment: For what it's worth, there are much better decompilers out there. Personally, I'd recommend Procyon and Krakatau. (Disclosure, I wrote Krakatau).

Comment: Basically You have error in your code. And compiler is giving compile time error. may be you have missed `;` or anything else.

Can you post your code here.

Comment: Umm like I said I didn't code this all I did was decompile two files and copy one file at the end of the other and was hoping I could recompile it back together and it would just work lol.... If you really want to see each file decompiled here they are: http://pastebin.com/70GEFRqN http://pastebin.com/v5jzMiJb (I do not claim rights to this code) If you can code it into one proper file for me and compile it that would be great! OR explain what I need to do if it is simple?

Comment: that is 8000 line of code. are you trying to compile them. there are missing classes and packages. i didn't find them. if you got them then provide now. there are lot of errors in it.

Comment: it is actually only 3000 lines or so but unfortunately a lot of spaces were pasted in for some reason... from pastebin... (idk why so there are alot of extra blank lines...) and i don't have the missing classes or packages... I think they are the minecraft jars and the source files of forge or something idk... Like I said all I have are the two class files...Would it help if you had the two original class files that were conflicting? Here they are if it helps: https://www.box.com/s/zoz12epcojgwignx6x0l Oh and is there a way to find out what files you need for compiling?

Comment: Oh wait or the actual mods themselves might help? I can give you links to those too: http://199.91.153.202/zszpjn1l9yzg/uwffm5ddomwq8hc/closetmod+1.5.2.rar http://205.196.122.68/l0jtjrx4u7zg/ttolbzy7h50oui6/MC+1.5.2+-+Player+API+universal+1.1.zip Other than that like I said I don't know and I am just hoping the mod authors will recognize the conflicts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except the fact that there are obviously missing libraries/import here (see compilation logs), you should have a look to the topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134784/why-filename-in-java-should-be-same-as-class-name).

In Java the default behavior is that the filename has to match the name of the class it contain which was fine when you had both files as I guess it was compiled properly (eg. you have yout .class files).

However when you copied one file in another, you will have to do some further changes to keep this rule valid, and you cannot just append two files like that.

Comment: hmmm so what your saying is that I can't just copy one file into another and I am missing file dependencies? and the filename must be the same name as the class file (which it is in my case) hmmm... Is there anyway someone here could fix the conflicting files issue for me plz? I could post the two files as one with the two files separated by a bunch of obvious spaces however there would still be the compiling issue...

Comment: But you will probably still be missing the libraries, and you cannot compile a class with missing libraries.

Comment: Would it be possible to create the missing libraries?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know much about the Java build system, your odds of success at doing something like this are very low.

At the very least, I'd recommend learning about the difference between .java and .class files, how to invoke `javac`, and how Java imports work. Once you have the basics out of the way, you can come here if you still have questions.

Also, use a better decompiler.

Comment: I got it decompiled though and merged I just need to know how to compile it back together?... and if it will even work if I can successfully do this... Like what do I need to do in order to compile it?

Comment: Umm wait would it be easier if I told you what files were conflicting and you looked at them??? Like I direct you to both mods that are conflicting and tell you what class file is conflicting?

Comment: @Radical924 Well I could probably solve it myself, but the thing is that I don't have the time or desire to do so. I don't even play Minecraft. Anyway, it's better for you to learn how to do it yourself, even if it will require an awful lot of learning.

Comment: ummm.... how long do you think that will take lol??? because it is just two files I want to be merged sadly like I said I can't get it too work...

Comment: @Radical Well if you don't understand Java, you have no hope of merging them properly. I'd recommend learning about Java bytecode as well.

Comment: What I should do is ask a friend or something that does know Java and can help me merge it properly or something... or hope that the mod author fixes the issues... in any case I posted the code above if anyone wants to merge it and compile it to bfj.class