# Compilation error with different file name

Tags: java, access-modifiers

```
class First    
{    
public static void main(String[] args)    
{    
System.out.println("File found");    
}    
}
```

(File saved with First.java)
javac First.java ---(no error)
java First  --- no error 

then I change name of class to "class Second"

javac First.java  --- (no error)
java Second   ---   no error

but If I add public and change the name of class to "public class Second"
then there is a compile time error that file should be saved with the same name as of 
public class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the file only matters if the class is `public`, in which case the file MUST have the same name as the class (class `First` must be in `First.java`).

If the class is not public, the file name has no importance.

Comment: But what is the reason behind that. What does JVM do in these cases, if I make it 'public' with file name different. And without 'public' file name different.

Comment: For more information, read [these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134784/why-filename-in-java-should-be-same-as-class-name).

Answer (score 0):

file name that contains a public class should be set to the name of the public class. And a file cannot have two public classes (same reason).