# A good way to check if a file is a Java source file

Tags: java, file, analysis

I have this model object representing a Java source file.

It has a constructor like so:

```
private SourceFile(File file)
```

I want this constructor to actually make sure (as much as it can) that the `File` it's being given is actually a Java source.

I have a batch operation that takes a lot of text files. Some of them are Java sources, I wan't a good way to differentiate them (other than file extension).

So has anyone been in this situation before and can you recommend a good way to check plausibility (not validity, for a validity check I'd need to compile it) ?

Comment: You don't have to compile it, but you could try to parse it. If it's parsable I guess it's safe to assume that you're dealing with Java source file.

Comment: if you compile and recieve error then its not java file (i mean atleast i would expect things to be working)

Comment: But if he was writing a compiler or interpreter the file may very well contain syntax errors.

Comment: Can the files contain snippets or fragments of java code, or are they syntactically correct java classes?

Comment: Since the compiler includes a syntax check this would be the best way to go.

Comment: Where do the text files come from? Why are some text and some java source?

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Answer (score 2):

I'd do two things:

1. Check that the file ends in `.java`.
2. Check that the file declares a `class` that has the same name as the file (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2134784/241294)).

Comment: That does not ensure that it is a Java source file. There are many languages that have "public class" keywords. And I guess he doesn't want to rely on a file extension.

Comment: By the way: This could have been a comment!

Comment: But how many languages that aren't java have files that end in `.java` and contain a `public class` declaration?

Comment: None comes to my mind but I ensure you "public class" won't be sufficient. On the other hand you don't actually need the class to be public (in Java) and if you would only search for the keyword "class" it could be Scala as well.

Comment: You're right, a java class doesn't have to be public and I updated my answer. I don't know scala, but my superficial search of the web tells me that they typically aren't saved as .java files.

Comment: Yes but you have to consider that a user would want to fool this automatic check. I don't know what the OP is using this for but if you use it for automatic assignment checking your test would complete succesfully without the file actually being a java source.

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure what the OP is using it for either, my rationale for this answer is that it would be a simple and fast way to check that it looks like a java source file. It is by no means fool proof or comprehensive.

Comment: I don't see reason for argument here. We all agree that there is no certain way to check other than compiling it. So the question is, how much validations are we willing to do in order to make sure. In this line of though I agree with @poida here a extension check + checks from proper class start (class, public class, comment prefix etc.) might be enough.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how accurate you want to be. If you want 100% you have to compile it. If you would be happy with something low you can check printable characters. Reasonable level may be achieved by key work check. And so on...

Comment: This could have been a comment!

Comment: It is not a comment. It is the answer. Because the question is out of "yes-no" boolean field. The question is about what could be considered a java file. And the answer depends on consideration point. So, I bring this to the attention of Simeon for him to understand there is no simple answer.

Comment: Crozin wrote a comment before you with exactly the same kinds of ideas and he made it a comment.

Comment: No he puts only one proposition. Also it is good it does not reveal that it is not a technical question but depends on what Simeon is trying to solve. Even if file is successfully parsed it may never be compile which means it may be or may be not java.

Comment: You could have added a second proposition as comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use [javaparser](https://code.google.com/p/javaparser/), on given link is [wiki](https://code.google.com/p/javaparser/wiki/UsingThisParser) how to use it. But in Java 1.6 the compiler has an API build in the JDK, through it you can access the [results of the Java parser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/lang/model/package-summary.html).

Comment: This looks to be exactly what I need thanks. I will update when I try it out

Comment: @Simeon if it is solution for you then accept answer please ;)

Comment: @Simeon If answer looks exactly what you need accept answer, it's good habit here.

Comment: @marekrendel I will accept the answer once I am able to check that it IS what I need, not that it LOOKS LIKE what I need. You can judge my acceptance ratio by my profile and yes I have (given my 4 years here) read what good practices are :) but I will take you advice into consideration...