# How do I get the source code to successfully run and compile on Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, class, applet

Start. Applet not initialized. My source code doesn't have any "bugs", but I am still unable to successfully run and compile the source code on Eclipse. How do I get the source code to successfully run and compile on Eclipse?

[image]

Comment: You have to declare the class in a file of the same name, e.g. `ConvertCelsiusToFahrenheit.java`.

Comment: If you go to the "Problems" tab on the bottom, you can see exactly what's causing these bugs.

Comment: "*My source code doesn't have any "bugs"*" not according to error message. Hover your mouse over underscored area and you should see error description.

Comment: _My source code doesn't have any "bugs"_ - every code has bugs ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have a made a common error, often situated with novice Java programmers. You have a class named `ConvertCelsiusToFahrenheit`, but the name of the file isn't the same. Remember, that one Java class is allowed per file (unless if nested or not public), and the file must have the same name as the class. See the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134784/why-are-filenames-in-java-the-same-as-the-class-name) for why a file must me named as its class

Comment: Downvotes? Why?

Comment: "Remember, that one Java class is allowed per file" is simply not true. I can have many classes in one file, even many public ones if they are nested.

Comment: Fixed answer @Pshemo