# I am new to Selenium, but why is Maven skipping over my test and telling me the build was successful?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium-webdriver, automation

I been trying for the past 3 hours to try to get a single `MyTest.java` file to run. But no matter what I try, Maven seems to want to skip over my test and tell me `BUILD SUCCESS`. But I wasn't try to build anything. I was just trying to "Maven Test".

When I run `MyTest.java` by itself, it runs fine , but for some reason Maven wants to skip over it.

This is what I wrote.

```
package SeleniumT;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class MyTest {

    @Test
    public void login() {
        //return "sample";
        System.out.println("########This is my first Maven project#######");
    }
}
```

My console output keeps saying there is nothing to compile, which makes no sense.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building maven-demo 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ maven-demo ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ maven-demo ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ maven-demo ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ maven-demo ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ maven-demo ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.287 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-02-15T17:27:11-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My POM file has all the dependencies required to run this. I don't have Maven Surefire plugin I think, but that shouldn't cause a issue, I am assuming.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>SeleniumT</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-demo</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>2.43.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>6.8</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

What could be causing Maven to skip my simple Java test?

[image: Maven folder structure]

Comment: Where is the class in the file system? take a read of https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Comment: Thanks for your response Taylor. I took a look at the guide. But I am not sure what you mean by class in the file system. When you say "file system", do you mean the pom.xml file?  I didn't know I had to add the name of each test in the pom.xml.

Comment: What folder is the class in?

Comment: It's in the [ src/test/java ] folder. I have uploaded a picture of the folder structure. I thought that was the right folder.

Comment: What are you typing on the command line?

Comment: Thanks for your response MivaScott. I am not using a command prompt . Unfortunately, I am not that advanced yet. I am right clicking on "maven-demo" workspace and selecting "Run as" and selecting "Maven test".

Comment: Dont' you get an error in Eclipse regarding your test class's file name and class name? [If your (public) class is called `MyTest` the file name has to be `MyTest.java`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2134784/1744774). 

The message "`Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date`" is OK since Maven recognizes if something has been changed in your source files since the last successful build. If not, no (useless) compile is performed and this message is printed.

Comment: [The `test` goal of the Surefire plugin is bound to Maven's `test` phase by default.](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Built-in_Lifecycle_Bindings). So, if you invoke the `test` phase (with `mvn test` or via an Eclipse Run Configuration) `surefire:test` is run automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your response Gerold. I was able to get it to work. But now I am facing a new challenge. I copied and pasted the exact same tests multiple times . But for some reason it's not running all the tests, unless I restart "eclipse". I have a good machine with 16gb ram and i7 processor. Why wouldn't it run all the tests?

Comment: Ignore the last part. It wasn't running because the test name didn't end with the word "test". Now it does. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I noticed your java file is called `apptest.java` but your actual public class definition is named `MyTest`. Rename the java file to `MyTest.java`. Such a difference usually raises compilations error, what makes me believe you Eclipse project is not set to **Build automatically**.

If that's not the problem, maybe the `Maven Test` option you have invoked is not invoking test goal. Concerning the "Nothing to compile" message, I'd suggest you to always perform a `clean` so maven get rid of previously compiled classes and build it from scratch again.

Summing up: right click on the project > **Run As** > **Maven Build...** > Type `clean test` on the **Goals** field > Click **Run**. Check if something has changed.

If you succed, the next time you need to run this again, this run configuration you've just created will be already listed on the **Run As** > **Maven build** menu.

Comment: Sorry, I missed your last comment where It seems you found the solution yourself. I hope my answer helps someone else if it get here for other reasons. :')