# Why can't the compiler find my public class in a source file that has 2 classes?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have 2 classes in a single Java source file, and the name of the source file is the same as the public class. When I run the source file, I get the following error:

[image]

```
 package inheritance;

 class clsnae {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("first");
    }
}

  public  class clsname {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("second");
     }
}
```

1. May I know why my compiler or JRE can't find my other file (non-public file)?
2. If I remove the `public` keyword, it just prints "*first*" and **not** "*second*", but after adding the `public` keyword to the class name, why does it still try to run the **first** class instead of running the **second** class?

Comment: post your code instead of screenshot and format your code.

Comment: I am not how you are running your program but I have tried the same example it is working fine. Eclipse asking me which class with the main method I want to execute and a pop comes with the selectable option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your code is fine**. There are two `main` methods and you can run any of them at a time.

For the first time **eclipse** would ask you which `main` method to run.
If you want to change later, **you can modify** your `run configurations` and choose your `main class`.

Goto Run configurations:
[image]

and then choose the `main` class:

[image]

**Here's the sample run:**

[image]

Comment: i tried what u said, but now im getting *Error: Could not find or load main class inheritance.clsname
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: inheritance.clsname
*

Comment: clean build your project, check your run configurations

Comment: glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

This has more to do with Java Specification.
The rule says if you are declaring a class as public the name of the file in which the class resides MUST have the same name.

However, The same rule doesn't apply if you don't specify the public modifier while defining your class. so you can save the file using any classname.

In your case Rule 1 violates.

For more details: Refer to the following answer:
[Why are filenames in Java the same as the public class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134784/why-are-filenames-in-java-the-same-as-the-public-class-name)

Since there are two main methods the Eclipse will prompt you with the classes having the main method to execute. in the current class.

[image]

Comment: how does it violate rule 1, my source file name is same as my public class name.

Comment: Lol! You just modified it before taking the screenshot. Just read the error message! The class name is different. Run it again

Comment: `"inheritence.clsnme"` instead of `"inheritence.clsname"`

Comment: i didnt modify anything , my source code file name is `clsname` and my public class file name is `clsname`. if i did modify u can still see the edit history.